# How to display different menu in a panel depending on node nr?

Tags: panels

I created a panel page. Say foopanel. This panel is displaying information based on the node nr. So in case of node nr 1 the url call will be: foopanel/1 (

I want to display a specific menu e.g menu-abc with node/1 and e.g menu-cde with node/2. So menu-xxx should be displayed in a block of foopanel.

How to implement this?

I see visibility rules in panels but do not see the nodeid. Should I do some php here? If so how should it be like?

I installed contexts but don 't see how I can manager this within a panel.

Every suggestion is very welcome to this. Thxs already.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using the following php code in the visibility rule:

return arg(1) == 1; for menu abc block
return arg(1) == 2; for menu cde block